# What is the shortcut key for Android Run and Clean Project in OSX?

Tags: android, eclipse, macos

What is the shortcut key for Android Run and Clean Project in OSX?

I have already tried ctrl + F11 but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>

Hope this help..

Answer (score 0):

for keyboards without the <kbd>Fn</kbd> and people using windows its <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>